# Modify JSON array element

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table

```
id int | data json
```

With data:

```
1 | [1,2,3,2]
2 | [2,3,4]
```

I want to modify rows to delete array element (int) 2

Expected result:

```
1 | [1,3]
2 | [3,4]
```

Comment: The second row should be `[3, 4]`?

Comment: The sample data looks more like that is a "native" array, not a JSON document. Is that really a  JSON? And if so, why are you putting a plain array into a JSON document? For a native array can use `array_remove()`

Comment: It is really json

Comment: > The second row should be [3, 4]?
Yes, I fixed it, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name suggests in his comment the proper data type is int[] in this case. However, you can transform the json array to int[], use `array_remove()` and transform the result back to json:

```
with my_table(id, data) as (
values
(1, '[1,2,3,2]'::json),
(2, '[2,3,4]')
)

select id, to_json(array_remove(translate(data::text, '[]', '{}')::int[], 2))
from my_table;

 id | to_json 
----+---------
  1 | [1,3]
  2 | [3,4]
(2 rows)
```

Another possiblity is to unnest the arrays with `json_array_elements()`, eliminate unwanted elements and aggregate the result:

```
select id, json_agg(elem)
from (
    select id, elem
    from my_table,
    lateral json_array_elements(data) elem
    where elem::text::int <> 2
    ) s
group by 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
First example works fine.
But how fast? =)

Comment: The first query should be faster than the second one but much slower than the analogous query on int[] data.